# Ошибка при попытке получить ексель файл в ответ на http запрос. Python/Flask

Tags: python, python-2.x, flask

Ошибка

> "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol."

В мейне хтмл шаблона есть:

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"  
meta charset="utf-8"/
```

Во вьюшке и в инит файле:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
flask_excel.init_excel(app)
import flask_excel


@app.route('/api/reports/services/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def reports_by_services():
if request.method == "POST":
    if method == '3':
    can_download = 1
    headers = [_(u'Терминал'), _(u'Услуга'), _(u'Цена'), _(u'Колво-продаж')]
    data_for_exl = []
    data_for_exl.append(headers)
    transactions = [(u'test3', None, None, 16, 1)]
    for tran in transactions:
        row = []
        for i in tran[0:4]:
            if i is None:
                row.append('-')
            elif type(i) == 'long':
                row.append(unicode(i))
            else:
                row.append(i)
       data_for_exl.append(row)
    return flask_excel.make_response_from_array(data_for_exl, "xls", file_name="export_data")
```

Ошибка возникает на сервере. Физического доступа к нему нет. Такой же код на локальной машине ошибки не выдает, файл получаю. Подскажите в какую сторону копать? Может в настройках nginx, что-то поменять? В пайтоне новичок. Использую python2 и Flask. Насколько я понял ошибка в том, что в функцию make_response_from_array я передаю данные в формате unicode а хтмл хочет в utf-8. А перекодированные данные в utf-8 функция make_response_from_array невоспринимает.

Answer (score 2):

Проблему на серевере решил обновлением версий пакетов
pyexcel,
pyexcel-io,
pyexcel-webio,
pyexcel-xls,
xlrd,
xlwt.